# Curl SSL error in command line of Cygwin

Tags: curl, ssl, cygwin

I'm just trying some basic cURL commands in Cygwin. I keep on getting the following error:

curl: (35) error:140773F2:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert unexpected message

I can force the command to work by using the -k option without SSL but that obviously is not a very good idea. There is nothing wrong with the certificate as far as I can tell and I do have the crt bundle installed and I have no issues with other htttps sites.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like potentially the SSLv3 is disabled on the server your connecting to. Are you not able to get more of an output by adding -vvv in your cURL commands? Also you could try different connecting methods like --tlsv1 --sslv3 --sslv2